# osx rvm passenger config?

Tags: apache, macos, passenger, rvm

Can someone please help me figure out why my passenger setup wont work? Here are the steps I have taken to install it.

- cd /Users/username/sandbox/my_rails_app
- gem install passenger --pre
- passenger-install-apache2-module
- Updated apache config files

**/private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf**

> ```
> LoadModule passenger_module /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302@my_rails_app/gems/passenger-3.0.0.pre4/ext/apache2/mod_passenger.so
> PassengerRoot /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302@my_rails_app/gems/passenger-3.0.0.pre4
> PassengerRuby /Users/username/.rvm/wrappers/ruby-1.8.7-p302@my_rails_app/ruby
> ```

**/private/etc/apache2/users/username.conf**

> ```
> <Directory "/Users/username/Sites/">
>     Options Indexes MultiViews
>     AllowOverride None
>     Order allow,deny
>     Allow from all
> </Directory>
>
> <VirtualHost *:80>
>    ServerName mule.local
>    DocumentRoot /Users/username/sandbox/my_rails_app/public
>    <Directory /Users/username/sandbox/my_rails_app/public>
>       AllowOverride all              # <-- relax Apache security settings
>       Options -MultiViews            # <-- MultiViews must be turned off
>    </Directory>
> </VirtualHost>
> ```

- restarted osx web server
- navigate to mule.local in browser
- **nothing happens** please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm a bit late, but if you haven't discovered it yet, check out [Passenger Preference Pane](http://www.fngtps.com/passenger-preference-pane). It'll make your life much easier. It handles Apache config.

Comment: Better late than never! Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

Get rid of the '# <-- ' things. Apache only supports comments on its own lines, not on the right of a config line.